# Distinct Find in Files search results in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I develop WPF and Silverlight application so I use source file links a lot. When I search for something, Visual Studio displays multiple same results in *Find Results* window - one for each file link which looks quite cluttered.

Is there a way (setting/plugin) to make the search results in *Find Results* window distinct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did one more search in Visual Studio gallery and I've eventually found what want: [Ultra Find](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/9fa9fdd7-1c06-45e3-a9f3-0381caab8f94)

It offers a few more features than the standard VS Find in Files but more importantly **it shows only distinct results for linked files**!

Comment: The link above to Ultra Find is broken (and it appears this extension no longer exists on Visual Studio Gallery?).

Comment: @DavidShepherd You are right, see also http://stackoverflow.com/q/15749546/505893

Answer (score 2):

If you are searching **C, C++, or C#** code consider using the **[Sando Code Search Tool](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/06f39a31-20ce-408c-afee-8a02b484db1c)** (a free, open-source extension for Visual Studio). It eliminates duplicate results in many cases, only returning a single result for each program element (i.e., class, method, or field) that is relevant.

Here is an animated gif of it in action:

[image]

**Full Disclosure:** I am the project lead for this extension so I may be biased :)

Answer (score 0):

There are much better "find" or "navigation" plug-ins out there.  I personally use [ReSharper's Navigation and Search](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/features/navigation_search.html) features to find whatever I need within a few keystrokes.

[CodeRush](http://devexpress.com/Products/Visual_Studio_Add-in/Coding_Assistance/navigation_tools.xml) and [JustCode](http://www.telerik.com/products/justcode/code-navigation-and-search.aspx) have similar features, too.

Answer (score 0):

By selecting "Display file names only" in the options for "Find in files" it limits the results list to unique entry per file with matches.

This may be a more useful view of the search results for your usage?

Comment: It is not as I need to view all matches in found files. And it displays one file multiple times anyway.

Answer (score 0):

For those coming back to this question over a decade later, I encountered the same issue when my `Find All` search was `Looking In` multiple folders of the same directory and `Include subfolders` checkbox was checked.