# What happened to the Visual Studio extension for "Ultra Find"?

Tags: visual-studio-extensions, findinfiles

What happened to the Visual Studio extension for "Ultra Find"? I've seen references all over this site and the Internet for this allegedly awesome extension. Here are a couple of links:

http://blog.arainia.com/2010/08/ultra-find-getting-started.html

http://coolthingoftheday.blogspot.com/2010/08/i-find-you-ultra-ultra-find-vs2010-add.html

And here's a S.O. link:

[How to exclude designer.cs from Visual Studio file search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1596337/how-to-exclude-designer-cs-from-visual-studio-file-search)

However, when I search in the VS **Extension Manager**, nothing shows up. It's as if the extension never existed.

Comment: I've added it as a discontinued app on AlternativeTo. Maybe someone adds something. http://alternativeto.net/software/ultra-find-for-visual-studio/

Comment: We can all vote for the feature in Visual Studio here:  https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio-2015/suggestions/2907413-add-exclude-files-to-the-look-in-options-under Doooooo it!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am guessing the author pulled it for some reason, perhaps in anticipation of updating it for VS 2012. I noticed this disappearance too a few weeks ago, as I would check now and then to see if there was an official VS2012 release.

I wrote up instructions for using the VS2010 extension for VS2012 [here](http://blog.outsharked.com/2012/09/using-your-favorite-visual-studio-2010.html). This is still relevant, if you still have it installed on VS2010 then this will allow you to get it up and running.

All very mysterious, I commented on his blog once or twice and never got a response. It's a shame because it's a great plugin. I still use it but, being seemingly unsupported, am looking for alternatives.

*Edit*

I switched to **Entrian Source Search** some time ago. This is commercial software but well worth the price. Not aware of any free alternatives that are nearly as useful.

Comment: Yep, it's a shame because there doesn't appear to be something else out there that has the same feature set. In fact, nothing else out there seems to be close to this. I'm wondering if someone out there has the original bits downloaded from the official site that he or she could share or upload to a semi-public Dropbox site?

Comment: Contact me directly - you should be able to find an address via my SO profile (can't seem to find one for you). I'll send you a copy of it. I don't want to post it anywhere, since it seems the authors wish that it be gone.

Comment: Sure. I see a Linked-In profile. Should I use that to contact you directly? I didn't see an email address anywhere else or on your Outsharked Blog. Anyway, I appreciate the offer. I want to respect the original author's wishes too, but I'm getting killed by duplicate search results for generated *.min.js files polluting the result set for simple find operations in VS2010...so I'm desperate for a solution. Seems like 'Ultra Find' is the only viable solution.

Comment: Funny, I thought it was public on SO, need to check sometime. Sure just email/linkedin/whatever me any way you can figure :)